# Colors of MATLAB tickmarks VS grid

Tags: matlab, plot

So, I am trying to maintain the (usual) black color of a MATLAB plots' grid, but I want to change the x-axis and y-axis colors to be white. If I do the usual set(gca, 'xcolor', 'w'); (and same for y), it changes the entire grid to be white, which is not what I want.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I have reviewed code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227412/matlab-grid-lines-with-different-color-on-one-axis) but it has not helped me much.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps an approach similar to this could be used: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1PAYMC/?solution=1-1PAYMC ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a quick hack you could redraw the axes with the color you want and the grid turned off:

```
plot(rand(10,1))
grid on

ax = copyobj(gca, gcf);
set(ax,'color','none','xgrid','off', 'xcolor','w', 'ygrid','off', 'ycolor','w')
```

Not elegant but works:

[image]