# Changing the tick color only in Matlab figures

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a figure and I'd like to be able to show the ticks positions (in white) but **keep** the tick labels (in black). For example, if you try:

```
imagesc(abs(peaks(10))); colormap('bone');
set(gca,'XTick',0:pi:2*pi,'XTickLabel',{'0', 'p', '2p'},'fontname','symbol');
```

[image]

You can see that the tick positions can't be seen. Matlab's documentation tells that the handle `YColor` and `XColor` can be used, but they also control the color of the tick labels. For example:
[image]

I have tried to get the tick out, but it doesn't look good. I tried playing with an approach similar to the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553720/matlab-remove-only-top-and-right-ticks-with-leaving-box-on), but without success. The last way I can think of is to "manually" rewrite the labels as text objects...  Would appreciate your input.

Comment: [This idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10235518/2586922) might be useful

Comment: You can now do this using the [undocumented axis rulers](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-rulers).

Comment: good to know! (I just needed that yesterday again :) ) you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there are no independent attributes for the ticks, only tailor-made tricks spring to mind.

The result of this

```
imagesc(abs(peaks(10)));
colormap('bone');
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:pi:2*pi, 'XTickLabel', {'0', 'p', '2p'}, 'fontname','symbol');
a = gca;
b = copyobj(a, gcf)
set(b, 'Xcolor', [1 1 1], 'YColor', [1 1 1], 'XTickLabel', [], 'YTickLabel', [])
```

is this

[image: Clone axes and modify attributes]

Comment: thanks for the answer. The problem I still have is that I also control the positions and labels of the ticks, so using your code overwrite the ticks in other places. (see my edited question)...

Comment: thanks Drake, this works, and the only thing to add is that the user needs to add the `xlabel` and `ylabel` after this code to get them look ok, otherwise they are get sketchy.

Comment: +1, nice! I would also add a `linkaxes([a b])` so that zooming and panning doesn't mess up the axes.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Good point, hence +1. "@"natan You are welcome.