# How can I make my grid lines thicker when printing them to a plot?

Tags: matlab

This is what they look like when I plot them on Matlab:

[image]

This is what they look like as when plotted as a png file:

[image: http://puu.sh/5fR2J]

The grid lines basically disappear and are barely observable when I plot them as a file. I do use the command below:

```
set(gca,'GridLineStyle','--')
```

But when I try to set the linewidth of the gca to be thicker, then the linewidths everywhere thicken (including the borders), which makes everything much uglier and harder to read.

Comment: Don't think there is an "easy" way for this. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580274/matlab-minor-grid-with-solid-lines-grey-color). They manually draw grid lines with properties they want.

Comment: yet another no.... http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/58956

Comment: have you tried all the renderers?

Comment: What size is the png? Depending on what you want to do with the exported picture (send it as mail, embed it in a document etc.) you might want to try a different picture format, such as eps. In the end, you could always draw the grid-lines yourself....

Comment: @thewaywewalk not sure on this, but I'd have guessed that the exported picture is independent of the renderer used to show it "live" in a figure?!

Comment: @sebastian, yes printout and figure window are completely different things. usually lines printed with the renderer `painters` are thinner. BUT you lose the vector graphic ability. I personally would print it as pdf or svg with `painters`, and then load the pdf with Adobe Illustrator etc. You should find a vector-graphic grid, which you can click on and increase the linewidth. Probably opensource software like inkscape should do it also.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought - that's why I proposed `eps` (2011b doesn 't have `svg`). Didn't know about the vector graphics connection with the renderer though...

Answer (score 2):

As last resort, draw the grid lines yourself.
It's quicker than one might think:

```
function gr = drawGrid(ax, linewidth)

    hold(ax, 'on');
    gr = hggroup();
    arrayfun(@(x) plot(gr, xlim(), [x x], 'k--', 'LineWidth', linewidth), get(gca,'YTick'));
    arrayfun(@(x) plot(gr, [x,x], ylim(), 'k--', 'LineWidth', linewidth), get(gca,'XTick'));
    hold(ax,'off');
end
```

It would become a bit messier though, if you'd want to have it self-updating when xlim/ylim changes...